# Uploading a folder of images with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, paperclip, image-uploading, jquery-file-upload

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to upload an entire folder filled with images?  What are some useful gems for this or even some existing github repos I can reference.  I cloned the following repo to my local machine and it works great, but you have to select each image individually.  It's sad, but this is too complicated for my clientele.

https://github.com/5minpause/multiple-file-upload

Is there a gem out there that would provide the same functionality as the app above but would allow me to select a single folder containing a bunch of images?  Then the images would extract themselves and download into the db.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Carrierwave https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

It has multiple file uploads at a time, but not sure if you can just upload a folder, instead of clicking each file individually.